# How to store public certificates in the truststore

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate, cacerts

I'm developing a microservice in Spring (Java), which needs to authenticate against an external webservice in order to perform some REST API calls.

**I've been given two files by the external webservice, a security certificate (.cer) and a PEM file (.pem)**

Now I'm trying to understand, how do I store the given certs in the truststore? so when I call their API endpoint, I won't get status code 401.

I was trying to use cacerts, but probably I'm not fully understand how things work.

This is where I'm at right now:

```
public class SSLLoader
{

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SSLLoader.class);

    public SSLLoader() throws Exception
    {
        loadSSLCerts();
    }

    private void loadSSLCerts() throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            SslContextUtils.mergeWithSystem(SSLLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/sa/cacerts"));             
            log.info("Loaded SSL from sa/cacerts");
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to load SSL certs: " + t.getMessage(), t);
        }
    }

    private InputStream fileToStream(String file) throws Exception
    {
        File initialFile = new File(file);
        InputStream resourceAsStream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
        if (null == resourceAsStream)
        {
            throw new Exception("File cannot be found - " +file);
        }
        return resourceAsStream;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you doing mutual TLS authentication?  Usually when using java you store certificate in trust store JKS file